# Replacement for XNA Lobby?

Tags: c++, networking, multiplayer

I am looking to implement with the Microsoft Windows Live game lobby. Since Microsoft has deprecated XNA, I am wondering if it is still possible to interact with the game lobby they provided in XNA (assuming it is not deprecated as well?).

I am doing this for an engine written in C++

In other words, I am wondering if Microsoft is still offering a game lobby system for developers (for indie developers that is). I am trying to track down the documentation for a possible replacement but I can only find resources for XNA.

If not, are there any good, possibly free alternatives? I have no problem writing my own lobby service but I would rather save the time with an already existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives are [GameSpy](http://www.poweredbygamespy.com/) and [SteamWorks](http://www.steampowered.com/steamworks/).

The latter requires "SteamWorks approval" before you gain access. 
Both are free.

EDIT: GameSpy will be [discontinued](http://www.maximumpc.com/gamespy_discontinue_multiplayer_services_may_31st_2014) on 31th of May, 2014!

Comment: I'm pretty sure GameSpy has been discontinued, or will be shortly. Or am I confusing this with another service?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.